# How to avoid unnecessary cast and extraneous variable involving ptr to ptr to ptr

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following code that totally works 100% fine, no errors, compile or runtime.  But it's damn ugly because I have to cast and use an extraneous variable when I'm sure there's a way to do without either.

```
structMSGB ***init_bstack(int Blk_Size,int Blks_N)
  {
  structMSGB **Mp=calloc(Blk_Size,Blks_N);
  void *M=(void*)Mp+sizeof(structMSGB*)+sizeof(structMSGB*)*Blks_N;

  structMSGB ***startStack=(structMSGB***)Mp++;

  for(int i=0;i<Blks_N;i++)
    {
    *Mp=M+(Blk_Size-sizeof(structMSGB*))*i-(i==1)*sizeof(structMSGB*);
    (*Mp)->blk_size=Blk_Size-sizeof(structMSGB)-sizeof(structMSGB*)-(i==0)*sizeof(structMSGB*);
    Mp++;
    }

  *startStack=(structMSGB **)Mp;
  return startStack;
  }
```

Specifically, it's the startStack variable that is pissing me off.  I feel there should be a way of doing without it altogether. The return value is the address  of a ptr to a ptr to a struct, i.e. It needs to return a ptr to a ptr to a ptr to a struct.

The result returned is the starting address of a memory block that is Blk_Size bytes in size and is composed of the following in order:

**ptr variable

table of ptrs of Blk_N length

sequential blocks of size Blk_Size - sizeof(ptr) except for the first block which is sizeof(ptr) smaller.

It's done this way to ensure that the entire memory allocation is used, no more and no less.

Comment: This is wrong `void *M=(void*)Mp+sizeof(structMSGB*)+sizeof(structMSGB*)*Blks_N;` you can't increment a `void *` pointer, you mean `void *M=(void *) ((char *) Mp + sizeof(structMSGB*) + sizeof(structMSGB *) * Blks_N);`?

Comment: Yeah you right I should have used char instead of void but in any case it works fine as is.  It's the startStack variable with the associated casting that is really bugging me.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings, they should help you fix things like this. And why are you using a `***` pointer, they are very rare to be useful.

Comment: I have lots of warning enabled but like I said the code works totally fine.  It provides the correct result so there are no errors in the code.  I just want to do it without the startstack variable and associated casting.  The *** is needed in this case as I need a return value that is the address of a ptr to a ptr table.

Comment: This **ALL** looks wrong.  If it produces the expected behavior then that's probably because code that depends on it is also wrong, but in a way that compensates.

Comment: Supposing that `Blk_Size` is the size of a `structMSGB`, this is wrong: `structMSGB **Mp=calloc(Blk_Size,Blks_N);`.  Variable `Mp` should be a single pointer, not a pointer pointer.

Comment: The code works totally fine can just be a coincidence, have you heard about undefined behavior?

Comment: @john bollinger The result I need is what I need.  Please don't make assumptions when you have no idea what the result is used for.  Blk_Size is NOT the size of the structMSGB struct.

Comment: This is certainly wrong: `structMSGB ***startStack=(structMSGB***)Mp++;`.

Comment: @poby: Could you show us what this is supposed to create? I'm having an incredibly hard time following your code. Unless `Blk_size` is larger than `sizeof(structMSGB*)`, you also have some undefined behavior from accessing beyond the end of the allocated array.

Comment: @john bollinger  The code has been tested thoroughly and works 100%

Comment: There is too much to explain as to exactly what it is for but suffice to say, it does work 100%.  I do not believe it leaks memory.  Show me where you think so?

Comment: I withdraw the claim about a memory leak.  The code is still bogus, though.  That does not preclude it producing the expected result, but this code would never get past code review in my shop.

Comment: @john bollinger  Well I certainly wouldn't want to work in your shop!  It works very efficiently without wasting any memory to do exactly what it is intended.  But the startStack variable irritates me as I feel sure there is a way of doing without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code invokes undefined behavior when it performs arithmetic on an expression of type `void *`.  Some compilers will treat that as if `void *` were `char *`, and if your code in fact works then that's what's happening, but it's still wrong.  And probably unnecessary, to boot.

Allow me to introduce you to pointer arithmetic.  Given a pointer `p` of type `some_type *` and an integer value `x`, the expression `p + x` is equivalent to `(some_type *) (((char *) p) + (x * sizeof(some_type))`.  By no coincidence whatever, that's also equivalent to `&p[x]`.  That is, pointer arithmetic is defined in terms of the size of the pointed-to object.

The code you present performs a lot of casting and arithmetic with explicit object sizes that could be eliminated by relying on ordinary pointer arithmetic.  For example, this ...

```
void *M = (void*) Mp + sizeof(structMSGB*) + sizeof(structMSGB*) * Blks_N;
```

... would be better written

```
structMSGB **M = Mp + 1 + Blks_N;
```

Similar applies elsewhere in your code.

More generally, good code rarely requires `sizeof` other than for memory allocation, and requires very few casts.  Any time you find yourself writing a cast, you should ask yourself why, and be sure you have a good answer.

**Update:**

As for getting rid of variable `startStack`, it looks like you could do so at the cost of some additional arithmetic.  You initialize it to the original value of variable `Mp`.  You then increment `Mp` at total of `Blks_N + 1` times.  At the only points where you use `startStack`, then, its value is equal to `Mp - (Blks_N + 1)`.  You could use that expression instead of a variable.  I certainly would not make such a change, though.

Comment: There's actually only 2 casts and I agree casts are horrible and I would love to get rid of them.  Both involve the startStack variable which I am hoping to do without.  I'm using sizeof mainly as sizeof(blahblah*) as a reminder as to how the code works.  It reminds me of the structure of memory area I am trying to achieve.  Like I said it works fine but I will take your suggestions on board as I am currently trying to simplify it.

Comment: You have casts largely because you are *lying* to the compiler about data types.  Given that you are storing a heterogeneous data structure in the memory you are allocating, the only possibilities for a consistent return type would be a pointer to an appropriate `struct` type, or a `void *`.

Comment: @poby, answer updated with a way to get rid of variable `startStack`, as you asked.  My advice to you is to not go that route, though.

Comment: You have given me some ideas and reminded me of stuff I needed reminding of.  Will recode and see if I can do it better.

Answer (score 0):

This is the greatly improved version that solves my problem (with help from @John Bollinger):

```
void *init_bstack(int Blk_Size,int Blks_N)
  {
  structMSGB **Mp=calloc(Blk_Size,Blks_N);
  Mp[0]=Mp[1]=(void*)&Mp[Blks_N+1];
  Mp[1]->blk_size=Blk_Size-sizeof(structMSGB)-sizeof(structMSGB*)sizeof(structMSGB*);
  for(int i=1;i<Blks_N;i++)
    {
    Mp[i+1]=Blk_Size+(void*)Mp[i]-8-(i==1)*8;
    Mp[i+1]->blk_size=Blk_Size-sizeof(structMSGB)-sizeof(structMSGB*);
    }
  return Mp;
  }
```

I use the return value thusly:

```
structMSGB ***MBp=init_bstack(4096,10);
```

I can then use *MBp to allocate chunks of memory using:

```
structMSGB *xb=*(--*Mp);
```

And when I'm done I can return the chunk with:

```
*((*Mp)++)=xb;
```

MBp also contains a value I can later use to free the memory - `free(MBp)`

I think MBp needs to be a *** type as it contains the address of the calloc'd block, the first 8 bytes of which contains a ptr into a table of ptrs.  This address is passed to allocate and free functions, so that the ptr at this address can be incremented or decremented accordingly, and also provide the chunk of memory requested.

The question now becomes, can the code be improved further?  I'm casting with a void * when I really don't like to cast but in this case, I don't see any alternative.  e.g. If I replace `*Mp=(void*)(Mp+Blks_N+1);` with `*Mp=(Mp+Blks_N+1);`, it works but gcc throws up a " assignment from incompatible pointer type" warning.  Is there a better alternative to using (void*)?